# Adding a CLASS on a DIV based off PC time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I should start that I am only very much a novice with JQuery but am trying to tackle something that with the help of online tutorials was able to get halfway completed. I need to add a class to a div during a certain time which I was able to achieve by using getHours() but I actually need to be able to specifiy the time as 8:30 to 8:45 and not just 8:00 to 9:00. Below is the code that I have so far. Does anyone have a moment to help? Thank you! As you can see I tried 9.48 but that failed but it works with just 9 && n < 19.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function applyclass() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();
    if (n > 19) $('body').addClass('night');
    else if (n > 9.48 && n < 19) $('#one').addClass('sunset');
}
$(function () {
    applyclass();
});
</script>
```

Comment: you need `getMinutes()` as well

Comment: Assuming the class is applied at 08:30, does it need to be removed at 08:45? (assuming the user stays on the page for that long)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `d.getMinutes()` to get minutes.

```
function applyclass() {

  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getHours();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  alert(m)
  if (n > 19 && m >= 30 && m <= 45 )
    $('body').addClass('night');
  else if (n > 9 && n < 19)
    $('#one').addClass('sunset');
}
$(function() {
  applyclass();
});
```

Comment: Thank you chipChocolate! Merry Christmas!

Comment: Actually maybe you could help me with further flushing this out. So far, I got an awesome little widget put together but am trying to write out the code to say that if it is after 5 PM to 11:59 then display the div. But I just can't seem to get it to actually show up like the others before it.   

else if (n > 14 && m >= 16 && n < 23 )
    $('#000').show();

Comment: @RossBethune - If you want to display the `div` between 5PM to 11:59PM, try this:---> `else if(n > 17 && n <= 23) { $('#000').show() }`

Comment: Is there anyway to include minutes into the calculation? Like 17:30? Where am I stuck is that I have an process that ends at 5:05 and I want that state (DIV) to display until midnight.

Comment: @RossBethune - [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/e00wn56h/), for time conditions between 5:30PM to 11:30PM.

Comment: You sir are a great person. Thank you!

Comment: I hate to keep bothering you but I keep running into road blocks. This was working and then I updated it to a different time and it stopped. It wouldn't work in Chrome with == but worked when I removed the second =..

<script type="text/javascript">

function applyclass() {

  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getHours();
  var m = d.getMinutes();

  else if (n = 14 && m >= 13 && m <= 15 )
    $('#935').show().addClass('night');

 if ((n = 17 && m > 29 ) || (n > 17 && n < 23 ) || (n = 23 && m < 59 ))
    $('#000').show().addClass('night'); 

}

$(function() {
  applyclass();
});

</script>

Comment: @RossBethune - The current time where I am is 3:11 PM, I've changed the time so that it will cover the current time as well. I ran [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4hqvcf5/1/) on Chrome and it works fine.

Comment: Your `else if` statement was before `if`.